# Can I delete snapshot but keep current state which is coming from that snapshot?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

Can I delete a VirtualBox snapshot but keep the current state which is under the snapshot?
The situation is depicted below:

[image]

What I want to do is, delete the "it's working" snapshot to save 10GB of disk space but I want to keep the current state.
Can I just delete the snapshot or will it erase current state as well? If not, is there a way to keep the current state while I get rid of the 10GB of the snapshot?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

**Delete a snapshot.**

This does not affect the state of the virtual machine, but only releases the files on disk that Oracle VM VirtualBox used to store the snapshot data, thus freeing disk space. To delete a snapshot, right-click on the snapshot name in the snapshots tree and select Delete. Snapshots can be deleted even while a machine is running.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/E97727/html/snapshots.html

Comment: I just deleted the snapshot and I can confirm that the current state was kept. I actually deleted the snapshot while the machine was running. Everything seems ok. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Just as a quick addition, I just deleted a snapshot on an Ubuntu 20.04 VM while it was running, and the file system in the running system disappeared.  Nothing but / was left.  Scared me to death.  When it finished, I reset the VM and it all came alive, but caveat emptor.

Comment: I tried doing this, and got a "not enough free disk space" error while trying to remove the snapshot. I have 29GB free trying to remove a 150GB snapshot (to free space ... :/)