# Deleted VM snapshots in file manager and broke my VM

Tags: virtualbox

I have a tree that looks like this:

[image: Snapshots]

While making a backup, i noticed that these snapshots take up a ton of space! I deleted everything except the 2 most recent files, one being 7.8GB and the other one 2MB. I deleted the files from the file manager, not the app.

Now trying to run the VM, i get this:

> Could not open the medium 'C:\Users\qwerty\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu
> 20\Snapshots/{8ba72d7a-5f5a-499c-9258-b1ff77e9c0cc}.vdi'.
>
> VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file
> 'C:\Users\qwerty\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu
> 20\Snapshots/{8ba72d7a-5f5a-499c-9258-b1ff77e9c0cc}.vdi'
> (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

Trying to delete the snapshots from the app looks the same:

> Cannot lock hard disk 'C:\Users\qwerty\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu
> 20\Ubuntu 20.vdi' when deleting a snapshot.

> Could not open the medium 'C:\Users\qwerty\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu
> 20\Snapshots/{8ba72d7a-5f5a-499c-9258-b1ff77e9c0cc}.vdi'.
>
> VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file 'C:\Users\qwerty\VirtualBox
> VMs\Ubuntu 20\Snapshots/{8ba72d7a-5f5a-499c-9258-b1ff77e9c0cc}.vdi'
> (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you shut down the VM first, or just pause it? Snapshots can be incremental, so shutting down gives you a known-good state to start back up from.

Comment: The VM was not active when i deleted the files. I should be able to delete old snapshots with virtualbox, but i did it wrong and realised too late: [Can I delete snapshot but keep current state which is coming from that snapshot?](https://superuser.com/questions/1476264/can-i-delete-snapshot-but-keep-current-state-which-is-coming-from-that-snapshot)

Comment: I had another but alike issue, except that I've left only the last snapshot and deleted the rest from the app manager. Seems VM breaks next snapshot while merging it with the previous being deleted. So try left more snapshots at the end. Additional rule is that make a snapshot from a stopped VM, otherwise it would crash if run it on another PC, otherwise you would have to drop the state and lose all unsaved data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to fix this problem is to restore the missing snapshots
from backup. This way no data will be lost.

Each snapshot keeps the *changed parts*, it is not a complete copy
of the VM. When deleting a snapshot *via VirtualBox*, its data is merged
with the previous snapshot.

As you deleted the snapshots via the file manager, required data is
now lost.

If you don't have a backup but wish to recover as much as possible,
try to build a new VM using a copy of the `.vdi` disk-image of the
damaged VM. With luck, the new VM will boot, but I'm unclear
about the actual state of its data.